# Check for contact before sprite enters another sprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am checking when a sprite touches another sprite, it will stop moving. So I am pretty much creating a barrier for the main player:

[image]

When the contact delegate is triggered, I set the player's velocity to 0, and it works perfectly to stop movement when it reaches the barrier. However, if the player hits the barrier, it slightly goes inside the node:

[image]

Therefore, if it goes left or right, it will "contact" again with the other two barriers on the side. It should be able to move left and right freely, even if it is touching a barrier. However, due to the main player going "inside" the barrier, it is triggering unwanted contacts. I figured the solution would be to check for contacts before the player goes inside the other sprite nodes, how can I check for that?

**EDIT**

I figured out the best way to create a barrier is to simply allow collisions to happen and make the barrier block have a great mass. What is the greatest CGFloat I can assign to a SKSpriteNode?

**EDIT**

They are still getting stuck in corners, even after setting the mass to a huge amount.

**EDIT**

I really like the suggestion of using SKConstraints, I tried doing this:

```
    var constraints = [SKConstraint]()

    constraints.append(SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(lowerLimit: 10),
                                                 to: ent[0]))
    constraints.append(SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(lowerLimit: 10),
                                             to: ent[1]))
    constraints.append(SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(lowerLimit: 10),
                                             to: ent[2]))


    mainPlayer.constraints = constraints
```

However, the mainPlayer goes right through the blocks. The blocks are not static, but since they do not collide, it goes right through them. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If player is marked that is in the contact, ignore other contacts. Make a property on a Player class that tracks this. Probably some other solution (eg to change its contact mask) but this came first on my mind.

Comment: I was also thinking a great solution would be to use the collision system, and make the mass of the barriers so big, that it would be as if nothing happened. I just don't know if adding a great mass or a density to a node will cause a collision that is pretty much canceled out. How are collisions calculated?

Comment: @pablo you need to use `@Whirlwind` or he won't hear you.

Comment: @Whirlwind please read pablos comment (they didn't @ sign you) :)

Comment: @Fluidity I will later tonight. Also, some copy pasteable code which can reproduce the issue would be helpful.

Comment: hey there, please upvote my answer that you accepted if you don't mind :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding an `SKConstraint` to the player (or to the boxes), so that after simulating physics your character will *always* be at least 1 pixel away from the boxes (so as to not trigger another velocity = 0).

Since constraints are handled AFTER physics in spritekit, this *should* work fairly well:

[image]

Something like this should work:

```
 let boxes: [SKNode] = [leftBox, middleBox, rightBox]
 var constraints = [SKConstraint]()
 for box in boxes {
      constraints.append(SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(lowerLimit: 5),
                                               to: box)
 }

player.constraints = constraints
```

[SKConstraint documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skconstraint)

note: you may need adjust the distance of the `lowerLimit` in the constraint to get the desired effect, or add more `.distance` constraints to your main player.. say, one for each corner of each box.

Comment: I really like this solution, but is not working on my code, is there some configuration that the nodes must have? I posted an edit on the question

Comment: @pablo I may have used the wrong constraint or messed something up. I will have to look at this more later :(

Comment: I got it to work, but it works as a circular border, instead of a square. Do you know how can I ensure it acts a square border?

Comment: @pablo you are going to need to use multiple `.distance` constraints but using a different set of prams than the ones I gave you.... look at https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skconstraint/1519746-distance

You will need to add 4 constraints per box, one for each corner of the box...

Comment: @pablo use `.distance(SKRange(lowerLimit: 10), to: ...insert CGPoint of corner of your box..., in: boxNode)` ... just add 4 constraints like that, one for each corner of your box

Comment: @pablo so in total for the three boxes you would have 12 constraints to add to the mainPlayer

Comment: @pablo I doubt it, but you can get creative with constraints to minimize how many you would need.. for example in the first picture you showed, you technically only need 4 constraints... (because all 3 of the boxes are aligned together which makes just 1 box .. hence only 4 corners). But if your boxes are moving around then yeah, you would need to give each one constraints...

Comment: @pablo Just keep adding constraints until you get the desired effect that you need. What I said may not be complete.. you may need to add another 1 or 2.. you may need to keep that center `.distance` after all, and then add ones to the corners. if you were working with a perfectly square box, then you would only need 1 constraint per box, not 4-5.  I cant necessarily tell you the most efficient way to use constraints, just that they are a good solution for your problem :)

Comment: The boxes are perfectly squared, but I'll try 4 constraints

Comment: @pablo ok my bad. I recreated your project and now I see more of what you are saying. I'm too tired to get the series of constraints right, but it should be possible. Play around with it some -- or maybe someone else here can fix it -- I'll still look at it later too

Comment: kept testing it out and it looks kind of weird, would it be better to join sprites together? is that possible?

Comment: @pablo I will have to try to come up with another answer for you or some more code. In the mean time, you can use constraints to put two nodes together.. .look at `.positionX` and `.positionY`.. there is also `SKPhysicsJoint`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsjoint

Comment: @pablo if you can throw up a github of your project i will download and check it out, or at least a gist for all your main source files to reproduce this issue